# How can I configure my domain in order that it works?

Tags: dns, domain

I have some webspace and registred a domain for that. My webspace provider said:

> Change your A- and MX-record to our IP 95.25.229.11  (modified)
>    You can also apply the IPv6 address: 2001:51d0:2:110c::2 (modified)

I didn't manage to get it to work. Here are some screenshots of my domain configuration and my webspace. Can someone help me?

**[Domain configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahzf0.jpg)**

[image]

**[Webspace interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrLOZ.jpg)**

[image]

Comment: In the first screen shot, add the name, such as `www` or `` (nothing), and in the target, add the IP address

Answer (score 0):

The "A-record" and "MX-Record" in the instructions refer to the DNS Resource Record Type.  In the first screenshot, there seems like an opportunity to create an A record.  Go ahead and put your domain name (e.g.: example.com, or enyorm.tk as shown in the question) into the first field.  The Target field is where you would put the IPv4 address (e.g.: 203.0.113.11 is a proper example, or 95.25.229.11 to use the example shown in the question).  That is what the World Wide Web (web pages) will use.

E-Mail can use an MX Record, so use the drop-down box to specify a Type of MX.  MX records often ask for a domain name that is looked up (e.g.: example.com, or enyorm.tk as shown in the question), a number for the preference/priority (which can be 100 or just about anything else...  the number really only matters if you specify multiple E-Mail servers, because the server with the lower number will be treated with more priority.)  You should also be able to specify the name of an exchange.  Pointing to a valid DNS name (e.g. like example.com, or or enyorm.tk as shown in the question) is preferred.  You might be able to specify an IPv4 address (like 203.0.113.11 or 95.25.229.11) and presumably that might work better in some cases (if their E-Mail server doesn't recognize a DNS name), but specifying an IPv4 address directly violates some standards.  So, it is better to specify a DNS name if that can work.

For IPv6, create an AAAA record, the name will be your website (example.com, or enyorm.tk as shown in the question), and the Target will be the IPv6 address (e.g. 2001:db8:51d0:2:110c::2)

Changes often take some time.  The time to update records was historically days, but now may be several minutes... perhaps even instantaneous.  However, many systems might not update quite so instantaneously, so I would allow several hours after a change before I conclude that it seems like it isn't working as expected.

Comment: I'll try that! What is TTL 14440?

Comment: 14440 is the number of seconds in a day.  TTL stands for "Time To Live".  In theory, any DNS client (any device) can safely cache DNS info about your domain for 14440 seconds without needing to check if you updated it.  According to this theory, you'll set the TTL to a very low value if you're planning to make changes.  The problem with this theory is that lots of DNS software, including servers, and even some ISPs, disregard the TTL value.  The tradition's proper practice would suggest setting it to 600 while you test changes, and then increase it later, but I really wouldn't worry about that